# How to create a form to trigger model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to know how to create a HTML form to send data to rails application so that specific model method `guess` gets triggered.

I managed to get this work in rails console, however even using HTML form guides from https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html I can't seem to get my head around this concept.

to generate the basic setup I used:

```
rails g scaffold Riddle content image_url
```

my model file:

```
models/riddle.rb
class Riddle < ApplicationRecord

  def guess(guess)
    content == guess
  end
end
```

If the guess is correct(equal to content of the current object) user should see "correct guess" on the HTML page.

Comment: Now I am thinking maybe it should be handled on the front end with JavaScript instead of on the server using Ruby?

Comment: The form gets submitted and is handled by a controller action most likely. So, you can call guess on the instance in whatever action handles the form. Pease provide your form along with the controller action you are submitting it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A form upon submit can hit a controller action. So you could do something like this:

Have a view which has the form has a form which makes a GET/POST request to an action in `RiddlesController`; lets call it `validate_guess` passing the required parameters `id` of the riddle and `guess` which is the guess that is a user input.

```
app/controllers/riddles_controller.rb

class RiddlesController < ApplicationController

def validate_guess
  riddle = Riddle.find param[:id]
  guessed_correctly = riddle.guess(params[:guess])
  if guessed_correctly
    render plain: "correct guess"
  else
    render plain: "incorrect guess"
  end

end
```

You would also have to declare a route for this in `config/routes.rb`. As this works on a single Riddle object; it would be a member_action for the Riddle resource.

```
resources :riddles do
  member do
    post :validate_guess
  end
end
```

---

**[Controller](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#what-does-a-controller-do-questionmark)** - Its the `controller` that renders the view and a view can only interact with the `controller`. `Views` dont directly interact with a model, and the additional controller layer does this, which provides us with a lot of structure, i.e. we can keep all data related logic in the model(though it tends to creep out of these sometimes :)). Deal with requests generation/handling at the `View/Controller` level and contact model to get/set info related to the business objects.

For example - your `guess` method is a good example. It checks whether a given value is a correct guess for a given `Riddle` object and returns a boolean as result(by comparing it to some attribute in the `Riddle` object). Going forward one could also add authentication in the controller layer, add caching or add more presentation logic. Let the model do its job of just telling the controller if the guess is correct or not for a `riddle`. The controller and view then deal with how to show the user that result. (e.g. [Internationalize](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) the text, style the text shown in the view or return the response in different formats like `JSON`/`XML`/`HTML` or maybe on a correct guess inform some other 3rd party service that the guess is correct)

Read more about the MVC pattern [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and some things it enables us to achieve [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller#Goals_of_MVC)